# validate directly in your if or create a function?

Tags: php, architecture

the question is kinda hard to put in words but I hope I make sense

what's best practice?

this

```
if($value < 5)
{
    //do something
}
```

or this

```
if(ValidValue($value))
{
    //do something
}

function ValidValue($value)
{
    if($value < 5) return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way to validate a value rather than creating a function that's not even required.

```
If ( $value < 5 )
  {
   #do something
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the first form, the other would add unnecessary millisecond to your code execution, as well as increasing the actual file size. When programing for big applications, every millisecond counts :-)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do the same validation from multiple places, you should define a function for it. This way, if you need to change the validation code, you just have to update it in that one place, rather than searching for all the places where you perform the test.

Also, if the validation is complex (rather than just a simple comparison as in your example), it's a good idea to put it in a function so it will have a meaningful name.

If the validation is simple, and you only need to do it in one place, you can just hard-code it there.